# Error: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. - Next.js using html tag <img /> ( with styled components )

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, eslint, nextjs-image

I know that in Next.js we have Image component, but the problem I have with it is that I can't use it as a normal HTML tag like `<img />`. I have to give it a layout, but there's no option to control it as a normal HTML tag, and besides that, I can't use framer motion with it.

So I just installed `next-images` so I can import images and use them of course, and everything works fine, 'till I npm run build the landing page to see some results, and there's this warning:

```
Failed to compile.

./components/Presentation/Presentation.js
77:13  Error: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element.  @next/next/no-img-element

Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

This is where I'm using `img` tag with styled components:

```
<PresentationUnderText2 src="/underText-Presentation.png" alt="" />
<PresentationScissor2   src="/scissors.svg"alt=""/>
```

What can I do to use `img` tag as normal?

Answer (score 134):

From Next.js 11, [ESLint is supported out-of-the-box](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11#conformance) and a new set of rules is now provided, including the `@next/next/no-img-element` rule.

You can disable this specific ESLint rule, like any other rule, in your `.eslintrc` file.

```json
{
  // ...
  "rules": {
    // Other rules
    "@next/next/no-img-element": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: For me, I had to reload VS Code or Restart Extension Host to get the warning to disappear.

Answer (score 13):

I do not have `.eslintrc` file. instead I place this line at the top of the page or component

```
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `img` tag in your project, you can disable the `no-img-element` ESLint rule that is causing the error by adding the following configuration to your `.eslintrc.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  rules: {
   "@next/next/no-img-element": "off",
  },
};
```

Although, I would recommend using the `Image` component instead as it provides several benefits such as automatic optimization, responsive images, and better performance.

To use `framer-motion` with the `Image` component, you can wrap it in a `motion` component like this:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import {motion} from 'framer-motion';

const componentName = () => {
  return (
   <motion.div>
     <Image src="/my-image.png" alt="my-image" width={500} height={500} />
   </motion.div>
  );
};
```