# Firebase storage image not displaying in nextjs application

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

I am using the Next.js template from Vercel and just trying to replace the logo image at the bottom with one that is stored in Firebase storage. I have configured the next.config.js and it does not throw an error but the image is not displayed. It is only showing the image missing placeholder with alt text.
This is my next.config.js

```
/**

* @type {import('next').NextConfig}

*/
const nextConfig = {

  images: {
  
  domains: ['firebasestorage.googleapis.com'],
  
  },
  
};
  
  
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I can also access the image in my browser.

EDIT 14/08/21**

When I replace the nextjs image tag with a standard html  tag the image does load so it seems to be some issue with next.

Comment: If you go to the dev tools on the Network tab, do you see the image request failing there?

Comment: Yes, I am getting '403 Forbidden' for the status code but when I put the URL straight into the browser it works and I get status code 304.

Comment: I am still getting this error. I would prefer to use NextImage for the prevention of CLS, caching and optimization. I have whitelisted the emulator storage domain too. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it using the 'unoptimized' property in nextjs

```
                <Image
                    src={item?.categoryImageUrl ?? placeholderImage}
                    alt={item?.categoryName || t("text-card-thumbnail")}
                    width={imageSize}
                    height={imageSize}
                    // quality={100}
                    unoptimized
                    className={`object-cover bg-gray-300 ${
                        variant === "rounded"
                            ? "rounded-md"
                            : "rounded-full"
                    }`}
                />
```

Read more about this at  [nextjs unoptimized](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Using the unoptimized prop fixes this but has anyone found a solution, that can allow using the nextjs optimization as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I got the same issue and sloved by chagning image tag from NextJs tag to normal  html tag. this will work, yes you will get an eslint warning but you don't have other opitons
Hope this might help

Comment: You can disable the ESLint rule that triggers the warning, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68224530/1870780.