# Text color is off in VS Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Recently, my text color has been of for js,jsx,ts,tsx files in VS Code.

I don't really know what happened but it's not working all of a sudden.

[image]

As you see, the file is detected to be a typescript react file, but I do not have any text coloring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VsCode Syntax Highlighting not working for javascript/typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470708/vscode-syntax-highlighting-not-working-for-javascript-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

This warn come from Eslint rules when using Nextjs, it advice that you should use  component from Nextjs. Follow this post to find your problem!

[Error: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. - Next.js using html tag <img /> ( with styled components )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68203582/error-do-not-use-img-use-image-from-next-image-instead-next-js-using-ht)

Comment: I'm not talking about the <img/>, do you notice the colouring is off in vscode? I am asking if there is a way to enable the text coloring again in VS code. I appreciate your help!

Comment: from today, I have the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade plugin JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly to v5.0.20221115

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding following settings :

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.tsx": "javascript"
}
```

Ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language

OR

This is caused by the Javascript and Typescript Nightly extension. You can either downgrade or disable it to temporarily fix it.

[image]